# Jmeter data set config not working in linux server

Tags: linux, jenkins, jmeter

My jmeter test plan is not running in linux server and doesnot provide much log as well.

Here is my folder structure-
[image]

And this is how jmx file is updated with csv data config

```
  <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Data Set Config" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="filename">PRIVATE_PROFIT.csv</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="variableNames">entity,displayName,companyName,ein,STREET,CITY,STATE,ZIP,Phone,email,website,cspTrustScore,extVettingScore,extVettingId</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="ignoreFirstLine">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
    <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
    <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.group</stringProp>
```

According to that filename the path of jmx file and csv is same basically both are in root.

If I change this to windows full path works fine but in linux server it doesnot. Also tried removing the csv config from my test plan then works fine but not with it.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running your test in [Distributed Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter):

1. You need to manually copy the CSV file to all the slaves, JMeter master only transfers the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) tree, all the external files needs to be copied to the machine or [Jenkins build agent](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) beforehand
2. If you're running a JMeter Slave process you can provide the desired log file location via [`-j` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as:

   ```
   jmeter -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j jmeter.log
   ```

   the [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file verbosity is controllable via [log4j2.xml](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML) file

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the path separator is `/`. In Windows, it is either `\` or `/`.

Update your JMX file with the full path location of your CSV file on the Linux machine. It will work.

Check your JMeter log to identify the issue accordingly.